# Redshift integration tests (or other SQL DB). Verify table contents using CSV files in Java

Tags: java, tdd, integration-testing, amazon-redshift, dbunit

I want to create integration test that checks any DB table contents without knowing the table structure. Some sort of testing framework, I put a set of CSV files with names like `table_to_test.csv`, the test picks those files and asserts equality with DB contents.

By documentation this is achievable using [DBUnit](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/howto.html#assertdata)

```
    IDataSet databaseDataSet = dbUnitConnection.createDataSet();
    ITable actualTable = databaseDataSet.getTable(tableName);

    // Load expected data from an CSV dataset
    IDataSet expectedDataSet = new CsvURLDataSet(resource.getURL());
    ITable expectedTable = expectedDataSet.getTable(tableName);

    // Assert actual database table match expected table
    org.dbunit.Assertion.assertEquals(expectedTable, actualTable);
```

Although this is exactly what I need, this solution appeared undocumented, inflexible and therefore possibly unreliable. I also was not able to quickly find DBUnit bug tracker.

I wonder if there is alternative solution. CSV to CSV comparison frameworks might also work, since on Redshift I can unload data from tables to CSV files.

Comment: You should explain "appeared unexpectedly buggy", including opening bug report(s) on dbUnit site.  Also explain what's "undocumented" and what doc you are looking for.

Comment: Undocumented part is how to use CSV data sets. For instance I was not able to find that I need `table-ordering.txt` file. As for bugs - for instance  sometimes CSV parser gets into infinite loop. I was not able to easily find dbunit bug tracker, therefore no bug reports. However, I need to say eventually I was able to setup assertions using dbUnit with CSV data sets. I'll post as answer.

Comment: Thanks for explaining.  

dbUnit bug or feature request trackers: https://sourceforge.net/p/dbunit/_list/tickets

Would you mind capturing your CSV usage info as patches/merge request to the docs?  Are you able to create one or more tests for how it failed for you so can fix for everyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I was able to use DB Unit. If you are using Spring you can setup DB connection in this way (@BeforeEach is from [JUnit5](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/))

```
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;
private DatabaseDataSourceConnection dbUnitConnection;

@BeforeEach
void beforeEach() throws SQLException {
    dbUnitConnection = new DatabaseDataSourceConnection(dataSource, schema);
}
```

For assertions you will need the code in the original question. You also will need to specify all the table names you are going to test in `table-ordering.txt` (the `resource` instance should point to this file). The file must be placed to the same directory where all the CSV files sit. Example of `table-ordering.txt`:

```
my_table_1
my_table_2
my_table_3
```

CSV files with expected data must have names `my_table_1.csv`, `my_table_2.csv` and `my_table_3.csv` respectively. If you need to assert `null` values you must explicitly specify the word "null" in CSV. Also watch out for data in your CSVs. In my case I had one extra blank symbol in the headline. In the text editor it was invisible, however the test was failing, and it was pretty hard to debug.

The CSV escape symbol is '\' .